# Creation of an object in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator

Isn't

```
 A a = new A();   // A is a class name
```

supposed to work in C++?

I am getting:

> conversion from 'A*' to non-scalar
>   type 'A' requested

Whats wrong with that line of code?

---

This works in Java, right?

Also, what is the correct way to create a new object of type `A` in C++, then?

Comment: Please! Go read a book about C++! Read about automatic vs dynamic allocation. Btw, there is NO garbage collection in C++...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it isn't. The new operation returns  a pointer to the newly created object, so you need:

```
A * a = new A();
```

You will also need to manage the deletion of the object somewhere else in your code:

```
delete a;
```

However, unlike Java, there is normally no need to create objects dynamically in C++, and whenever possible you should avoid doing so. Instead of the above, you could simply say:

```
A a;
```

and the compiler will manage the object lifetime for you.

This is extremely basic stuff. Which C++ text book are you using which doesn't cover it?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I just felt so confident that it is correct while writing it. I think it is because thats how we do it in Java.

Comment: @cambr Java and C++ have almost nothing in common, apart from trivial syntactical similarities. Your Java experience won't be of much use in learning C++, which is why you need to read a good book - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @cambr:  Java has abstractions C++ just can't get away with, for good or ill.  Almost all Java variables are actually pointers, from a C or C++ point of view, so it doesn't need to be specified.  C and C++ have both dynamic data objects referred to by pointer, and local objects that are not referred to by pointers.  Going from Java to C++ is going to involve learning some new concepts.

Answer (score 3):

`new A()` returns a pointer `A*`.  You can write

```
A a = A();
```

which creates a temporary instance with the default constructor and then calls the copy constructor for a or even better:

```
A a;
```

which just creates a with the default constructor.  Or, if you want a pointer, you can write

```
A* a = new A();
```

which allows you more flexibility but more responsibility.

Comment: `A()` creates a temporary object with *value-initialization*, not necessarily with default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `new` is used when you want to instantiate a pointer to an object:

```
A* a = new A();
```

It gets allocated onto the heap.. while when you don't have a pointer but just a real object you use simply

```
A a;
```

This declares the object and instantiate it onto the stack (so it will be alive just inside the call)

Answer (score 1):

You need `A* a= new A();`

`new A();` creates and constructs an object of type `A` and puts it on the heap.  It returns a pointer of that type.

In other words `new` returns the address of where the object was put on the heap, and `A*` is a type that holds an address for an object of type `A`

Anytime you use the heap with `new` you need to call an associated `delete` on the address.

Answer (score 1):

`new` gets you a pointer to the created object, therefore:

```
A *a = new A();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, new returns a pointer, so you need to declare the a's type as 'A*'.
Second, unlike Java, you don't need parenthesis after A:

A* a = new A;