# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'classname *' to 'classname'

Tags: c++, class, instance

I have a class defined called extBlock.

I then make an instance of that class with this

```
extBlock mainBlock = new extBlock(1, 1024);
```

I get this error:
 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'extBlock *' to 'extBlock'

Can anyone help me with why I am getting this error.

I have seen examples online of declaring it like this with a pointer

```
extBlock *mainBlock = new extBlock(1, 1024);
```

But if I do it this way it does not let me call the functions of mainBlock

Comment: You should put your code on a new line and indent every line with four spaces.

Comment: You might consult one of the introductory C++ books listed in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647660/creation-of-an-object-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't C#: `new extBlock` returns a pointer to an `extBlock`, and you're trying to assign that pointer to a value type (which would be an incompatible cast).

What you want to write here is

```
extBlock mainBlock(1, 1024);
```

And the reason you couldn't call methods on the second code snippet was probably because you were using the `.` operator instead of the `->` ([arrow](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/structs/arrow.html)) operator needed to dereference a pointer.

Answer (score 13):

Read up on your C++ syntax:

```
extBlock mainBlock(1, 1024); // create a class instance (object) on the stack
mainBlock.memberFunction(); // call a member function of a stack object

extBlock * ptrBlock = new extBlock(1, 1024); // create an object on the heap
ptrBlock->memberFunctions(); // member access through pointers has different syntax
delete ptrBlock; // must deallocate memory when you're done with a heap object
```

Answer (score 9):

Switching from Java/C#?

In C++, to initialize an object on stack, you just need to use

```
extBlock mainBlock (1, 1024);
...
mainBlock.call_func(1,2,4,7,1);
```

The `new` operator creates an object on heap, and return the pointer to it. To access functions from a pointer, you need to dereference it with `*`:

```
extBlock* mainBlock = new extBlock(1,1024);
...
(*mainBlock).call_func(1,2,4,7,1);
```

In C and C++, `a->b` can be used in place of `(*a).b`:

```
mainBlock->call_func(1,2,4,7,1);
```

Also, C++ doesn't have Garbage Collection by default, so you need to deallocate with `delete` explicitly:

```
delete mainBlock;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this, like you had:

```
extBlock *mainBlock = new extBlock(1, 1024);
```

but then you call functions using `->` instead of `.`, like this:

```
mainBlock->FunctionOnIt(...);
```

Don't forget to delete it when it's no longer needed.

```
delete mainBlock;
```

Answer (score 1):

`new` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, where the constructor has initialized your object. Thus you need to use `extBlock *mainBlock = new extBlock(1, 1024);`. You can call the methods afterwards via `mainBlock->someMethod()` or `(*mainBlock).someMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword *always* assigns to a pointer. What you need to do is something like this:

```
extBlock *mainBlock = new extBlock(1, 1024);
mainBlock->functionName();
```

Since mainBlock is now a pointer, the `.` operator won't work anymore to reference fields or methods and the `->` operator must be used in its place.